# Problems testing async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I've stumbled across a problem of testing the asynchronous code.

Here's the code of my function:

```
export default base64String =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const image = new Image();

    image.onload = () => {
      const dimensions = {
        width: image.width,
        height: image.height,
      };

      resolve(dimensions);
    };
    image.onerror = err => reject(err);

    image.src = base64String;
  });
```

It takes in a `base64` encoded string and returns width and height of an image;

The test looks the following:

```
import checkBase64 from '../src/helpers/check-base64';

import base64String from './base64String';

test('should return width and height of an image in base64', async () => {    
  const result = await checkBase64(base64String);
});
```

The problem is that the test fails with the error:

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
```

I was following [jest docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html#async-await) and [some stack overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251302/how-to-test-asnyc-code-with-jest-or-test-image-onload-with-jsdom) but neither of them helped

Comment: Is it because you're setting the `src` before attaching the `onload` event?  Since you're setting the source from an encoded string, it might "load" it synchronously, so your event handler never fires.

Comment: I don't see any assertions in the test. Jest might be erroring because it's expecting an assertion, but an assertion isn't being done. Unless that's what checkBase64 is doing?

Comment: @JamesThorpe, I've updated my code (in my editor and here) with no success. I get the same error

Comment: Could you show the source of `checkBase64`? @IvanPrizov

Comment: @kingdaro The first code block in my question is `checkBase64`. I'm using a default export

Comment: Because your not returing the promise.. :)  `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {`

Comment: @Keith, I guess, I do, since I don't have curly braces after  the `=>` sign

Comment: Oh, indeed.. forget about that shortcut.  I was making a snippet and of course you don't get `module.exports` and used a normal function and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The `Image` constructor only exists in the DOM, and Jest tests are run in Node. It looks like the promise returned from the checkBase64 function is failing silently when trying to access `Image`. You'll need to mock it, either with something minimal (`global.Image = ...`) or something fully-featured like [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom).

Comment: I've tried both of your suggestions, but they didn't help. When I was trying to use `expect.assertions(2)` I got an error `Expected two assertions to be called but received zero assertion calls`. BTW, jest tests work fine without `expect` or `done`.  They just get passed

Comment: I edited my answer with an example of how expect.assertions should be used. The error message you're giving me tells me that the checkBase64 function might not actually resolve. What happens if you `console.log(result)`?

Comment: Also... don't jest tests run in node? Image doesn't exist in node. If _that's_ the issue, I'll rewrite my answer.

Comment: Ou... I guess that's the issue. I mean, I didn't really know that `image` doesn't exist in node

Comment: I see. I suspect the promise is silently failing, then. Editing my answer