# How to test img.onload using Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm stuck with `img.onload` event testing. I know that this is an async operation and it should be maybe mocked, but I still couldn't figure out how to solve the problem. I've also seen a couple of similar cases, but they are different from this one.

Previously visited:

- [How do you use Jest to test img.onerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462665/how-do-you-use-jest-to-test-img-onerror)
- [How to test asnyc code with Jest ( or test "image.onload" with jsdom )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251302/how-to-test-asnyc-code-with-jest-or-test-image-onload-with-jsdom)
- [How do I test `image.onload` using jest in the context of redux actions (or other callbacks assigned in the action)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273782/how-do-i-test-image-onload-using-jest-in-the-context-of-redux-actions-or-othe)

Code to test:

```
  function funcToTest(img, callback) {
    const img = new Image()
    img.src = img

    img.onload = () => {
      callback(true) // should return callback with true on finish
    }

    img.onerror = (e) => {
      callback(false) // should return callback with false on error
      console.log(e) 
    }
  }

  funcToTest()
```

Testing environment:

```
describe('tet it', () => {
  it('test', done => {
    const callback = status => {
      expect(status).toEqual(true) // but nothing happen
      done()
    }

    funcToTest('some_image', callback)
  })
})
```

Also I get an error on the finish:

```
    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
        > 2 |   it('test', done => {...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might seem silly, but have you tried moving `img.src = img` to the end of `funcToTest`, i.e. after you've defined the `onload` / `onerror` functions?

Comment: Why are you testing img.onload at all? Is that code that you're maintaining? It seems like a mistake to test code that you don't maintain.

Comment: @DovRine because I need to test the callback at the end of its work. That's why.

Comment: @MaxTravis: Why can't you just test the callback? Does img.onload provide arguments necessary to the callback? Not only that, but doing it this way will probably slow your tests down a lot.

Comment: @MaxTravis: is Image the class that you're testing? It seems like the function under test is FuncToTest. I think you should mock Image to have onload and onerror events in order to test FuncToTest.

Comment: @DovRine nope, that is a pure func. And it just a piece of the whole logic to test, that main problem that I stuck on receiving a callback once "image" is loaded.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

While this was answered, I disagree with the purpose of the solution.

We shouldn't write tests to pass coverage, we should write tests that prove a point, and ensure pieces of code behave as expected.

The way to test it is to mock the Image constructor and replace it with something that will invoke the `onload` function.

```js
describe('test it', () => {

  it('test', done => {
    global.Image = class {
      constructor() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.onload(); // simulate success
        }, 100);
      }
    }

    const callback = status => {
      done()
    }

    funcToTest('some_image', callback)
  })
})
```

The method just assumes that the 'browser' will download the image within 100 ms, you can tweak the code for failure, or move parts of it to `beforeEach` if you need to share this behavior between tests.

Comment: Error: "Types of construct signatures are incompatible. Type `new () => Image` is not assignable to type `new (width?: number, height?: number) => HTMLImageElement`. Type `Image` is missing the following properties from type `HTMLImageElement`: align, alt, border, complete, and 260 more."

Comment: @Jago that's a typescript error, the code above is not written in safe typescript. the mocked image here is obviously not a fully mocked image implementation.

If i were you I would just ts-ignore it as it's probably not worth the hassle to add type safety here

Comment: I've applied this solution to my tests, the problem i'm facing now is that when I run the onload multiple times it causes the onload function to error out with this error: `TypeError: this.onload is not a function.` Think its because jest doesn't clean the overriden implementation.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, you'll need to clean up your "fixtures" at the end of every test - there's a before() and after() steps for tests. (beforeEach as well if I remember correctly)

Answer (score 5):

The function to be tested:

`index.ts`:

```js
function funcToTest(imgUrl: string, callback: Function) {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = imgUrl;

  img.onload = () => {
    callback(true);
  };

  img.onerror = e => {
    callback(false);
    console.log(e);
  };

  return img;
}

export { funcToTest };
```

- Unit test solution 1:

```js
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

import { funcToTest } from './';

describe('test suites', () => {
  it('onload', done => {
    const callback = jest.fn(status => {
      expect(status).toBe(true);
      done();
    });

    const imageUrl = 'https://github.com/mrdulin';
    const img = funcToTest(imageUrl, callback);
    if (img.onload) {
      const event: any = {};
      img.onload(event);
    }
  });

  it('onerror', done => {
    const consoleLogSpyOn = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const callback = jest.fn(status => {
      expect(status).toBe(false);
      done();
    });

    const imageUrl = 'https://github.com/mrdulin';
    const img = funcToTest(imageUrl, callback);
    if (img.onerror) {
      const event: any = { message: 'some error' };
      img.onerror(event);
      expect(consoleLogSpyOn).toBeCalledWith(event);
    }
    consoleLogSpyOn.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

Unit test result and coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57092154/index.spec.ts
  test suites
    ✓ onload (8ms)
    ✓ onerror (8ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    { message: 'some error' }

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.821s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57092154

**UPDATE: undeleted answer, unit test solution 2**

You can use [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) method to create getter and setter for `Image.prototype.onload` method. Then, you can get the `onload` function in your test cases and execute it manually.

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { funcToTest } from './';

describe('57092154', () => {
  let onloadRef: Function | undefined;
  let onerrorRef: Function | undefined;
  beforeAll(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(Image.prototype, 'onload', {
      get() {
        return this._onload;
      },
      set(onload: Function) {
        onloadRef = onload;
        this._onload = onload;
      },
    });
    Object.defineProperty(Image.prototype, 'onerror', {
      get() {
        return this._onerror;
      },
      set(onerror: Function) {
        onerrorRef = onerror;
        this._onerror = onerror;
      },
    });
  });
  it('should handle onload event', () => {
    const callback = jest.fn();
    funcToTest('./test.png', callback);
    onloadRef!();
    expect(callback).toBeCalledWith(true);
  });

  it('should handle onerror event', () => {
    const callback = jest.fn();
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log').mockImplementation(() => 'suppress error');
    funcToTest('./test.png', callback);
    const mErr = new Error('network');
    onerrorRef!(mErr);
    expect(callback).toBeCalledWith(false);
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith(mErr);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/57092154/index.test.ts
  57092154
    ✓ should handle onload event (4 ms)
    ✓ should handle onerror event

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.741 s
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, sir!

Comment: Meanwhile, this test is doesn't make any img load be like a "truthly tested" on `.onload` event. It just invokes a provided callback since we invoke `img.onload` event in fact. It does not have any sense, unfortunately...

Comment: The problem here is that you can remove the onload invocation from the funcToTest and the test would pass, When testing, the test should not have any inner knowledge of how things work - That callback could change to a setTimeout or anything else

Comment: Your unit test solution 2 is perfect. It does require an updated version of js to Flow, but works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Typescript version of the @Patrick answer:

```
type ImageConstructor = new (
  width?: number | undefined,
  height?: number | undefined
) => HTMLImageElement;

describe('1234', () => {
  global.Image = class {
    onload: () => void;

    constructor() {
      this.onload = jest.fn();
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.onload();
      }, 50);
    }
  } as unknown as ImageConstructor;

 it("should call onload", () => {})

)};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have some logic in [Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image)'s `onload` event handler and want to test if it was applied correctly, you can actually create an image [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) programmatically using [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API).

Consider this function:

```
const imageDimensions = (
  file: File
): Promise<{ width: number; height: number }> =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image()

    img.onload = () => {
      const { naturalWidth: width, naturalHeight: height } = img
      resolve({ width, height })
    }

    img.onerror = () => {
      reject('There is something wrong with this image')
    }

    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
  })`
```

So given a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) (blob) it returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which resolves to an object with dimensions. Or rejects with an error.

How do we test `onload` part? You can programmatically create a blob in your tests, but `new Blob(['a'.repeat(10)], { type: 'image/jpeg' })` will not trigger `onload`, since this is not really an image.

No need to mock anything, use JSDOM or anything like that. Canvas to the rescue! This could be tested as simple as that:

```
describe('imageDimensions', () => {
  it('should resolve with correct dimensions given an IMAGE blob', done => {
    // although this canvas has no actual graphics, it is still an image and it contains image metadata, thus onload() will be fired
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    canvas.width = 10
    canvas.height = 10

    canvas.toBlob(
      async blob => {
        const { width, height } = await component.imageDimensions(blob)
        expect(width).toBe(10)
        expect(height).toBe(10)
        done()
      },
      'image/jpeg',
      0.1
    )
  })

  it('should reject with an error if the file provided does NOT seem to be an image', async () => {
    const file = new Blob(['a'.repeat(10)], { type: 'application/pdf' })

    try {
      await component.imageDimensions(file)
    } catch (error) {
      expect(error).toBe('There is something wrong with this image')
    }
  })
})
```

In this example the Canvas is being created and then converted to a blob, which is similar to that being generated by a browser when user has selected some image file.

P.S. this is both Jest and Jasmine compatible.

Comment: You might need to install `npm install --save-dev canvas` as well. That worked for me, `jest-canvas-mock` didn't.
https://github.com/hustcc/jest-canvas-mock/issues/2#issuecomment-369608229

Comment: Good to know. I have a standard-ish Angular configuration and don't have any of these dependencies installed, yet it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jsdom you can solve this by simply adding the following to your jest config:

`"testEnvironmentOptions": { "resources": "usable" }`

By default jsdom will not load resources such as scripts, images, etc. This setting allows jsdom to load resources and make http requests, thus the `Image.onload` callback can be triggered.

However it's best to not make http requests in your tests, so set `Image.src` to a base64 encoded image. This will trigger the `onload` callback almost immediately. You can also test the `onerror` callback. For example:

```js
test('jsdom image callbacks work', async () => {

  const img = new Image();
  img.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7';
  img.onload = jest.fn();
  img.onerror = jest.fn();

  await delay(0);

  expect(img.onload).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  expect(img.onerror).toBeCalledTimes(0);

});
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57139876/737393