# React unit test image on load

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using this "async image" component but I have problems in unit tests, for the "load" success section with the image

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const AsyncImage = (props) => {

    const [loadedSrc, setLoadedSrc] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoadedSrc(null)
        if (props.src) {
            const handleLoad = () => {
                setLoadedSrc(props.src)
            }
            const image = new Image()
            image.addEventListener('load', handleLoad)
            image.src = props.src

            return () => {
                image.removeEventListener('load', handleLoad)
            }
        }
    }, [props.src])

    if (loadedSrc === props.src) {
        return (
            <img {...props} />
        )
    }

    return null
}

export default AsyncImage
```

Unit test:

```
    global.Image = class {
            constructor() {
                this.onload = jest.fn();
                this.addEventListener = jest.fn()
                this.removeEventListener = jest.fn()
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.onload();
                }, 50);
            }
        };

   test("render AsyncImage", async () => {

        const logo = LOAD_SUCCESS_SRC

        let container
        await act(async () => {
            container = render(
                <Router>
                    <Provider store={store}>
                        <AsyncImage
                            src={logo}
                            alt="test.png"
                            className='img-fluid img-catalogCards'
                        />
                    </Provider>
                </Router>
            )
        })

    })
```

At the beginning of the unit test add the image class, it enters the setTimeout but still does not enter the handleLoad function

How do I get to the handleLoad function when loading the image so that it enters the return section of the image?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57092154/how-to-test-img-onload-using-jest?